# 2000 Pontiac Bonneville lacks power

Tags: pontiac, bonneville

I put new plugs and coil packs on my car.  It runs but it slowly gains speed.  What's wrong with it? It doesn't have a catalytic converter and my oil isn't mixing with coolant.  This car doesn't have the supercharged engine.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you sure you put the plug wires back in the right spots (correct firing order)? What was the reason you were changing out the plugs/coil packs in the first place? IIRC, the 2000 Bonneville has a waste spark design?

Comment: Will, I edited your question to make it easier to read.  I hope I didn't change any of your meaning.  Any more details, and what you have tried would help.  As it stands, this is a very broad question and will be hard to answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue suddenly appeared after your repair, check the following:

1. Did you use the correct model of spark plugs?
2. Are the spark plugs correctly gapped for your engine?
3. Did you use the correct ignition coil for your engine?
4. Did you reconnect the correct spark plug to the correct ignition coil output?